# Select latest entries for a list of IDs

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I've got a following table:

```
create table MyData
(
  id bigserial primary key,
  registered timestamp not null,
  deviceID int not null,

  someData int,

  -- a bunch of other stuff
);
```

I also have a list of `deviceID`s. Each `deviceId` from this list has a bunch of entries in `MyData` having different `registered` timestamp.

What I need is to get `someData` for each `deviceId` from an entry having the latest `timestamp` using JPA query.

Of course, I can write a query fetching required data for a single `deviceId`, like

```
SELECT d.someData from MyData d WHERE d.deviceID =:dev_id ORDER BY registered DESC
```

adding `.setMaxResults(1)`, looping it for all `deviceID`s. How do I put it into a single query?

Comment: C'mon dude, finish the sentence - the suspense is killing me!

Comment: @Raad Sorry, no suspense intended:-]

Comment: You can `SELECT d.someData from MyData d WHERE d.deviceID in (SELECT DISTINCT d2.deviceID from MyData d2) ORDER BY registered DESC` or `SELECT d.someData from MyData d WHERE d.deviceID = :dev_id ORDER BY registered DESC LIMIT 1` but not both together - you need to loop for that.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the rows for all `deviceid`s with the latest "registered" value

```
select id, 
       deviceid,
       somedata,
       registered
from (
   select id,
          deviceid,
          somedata,
          registered,
          max(registered) over (partition by deviceid) as max_registered
   from myData
) t
where registered = max_registered
order by deviceid;
```

If there is more than one "max" value for `registered` for the same deviceId, you'd get more than one row for each device. If you don't want that, you can use:

```
select id, 
       deviceid,
       somedata,
       registered
from (
   select id,
          deviceid,
          somedata,
          registered,
          row_number() over (partition by deviceid order by registered desc) as rn
   from myData
) t
where rn = 1
order by deviceid;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your query, add to the select statement `MAX(registered)`.  Therefore, it will select the latest timestamp registered

example:

```
SELECT d.someData, MAX(registered) from MyData d WHERE d.deviceID =:dev_id
```

Comment: Alright, but that implies looping over all the ids - that's precisely what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query which would fetch data for each device having maximum registered timestamp.

```
SELECT d.deviceID, 
       min(d.someData) 
FROM MyData d 
WHERE d.registered IN (Select MAX(m.registered) 
                       from MyData m 
                       where m.deviceID = d.deviceID) 
group by d.deviceID;
```

Alter query to include/exclude fields in select,group-by accordingly.